# Ambiguous overload after arithmetic between different types of Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have encountered a problem in a function overload for different kinds of Eigen matrices (a column and a matrix to be precise). The overload fails when the input is the result of some simple arithmetic. In particular:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> MatD;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic,              1, Eigen::ColMajor> ColD;

ColD multiply(const ColD &A){ return 2. * A; }
MatD multiply(const MatD &A){ return 2. * A; }

int main()
{
  ColD A = ColD::Ones(10);
  MatD B = MatD::Ones(10,10);

  // overload is correct
  std::cout << multiply(A) << std::endl;
  std::cout << multiply(B) << std::endl;

  // compiler error: "error: call to 'multiply' is ambiguous"
  std::cout << multiply(A+A) << std::endl;
  std::cout << multiply(B+B) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I.e. the overload based on `A` and `B` is compiled correctly. But the compiler is unable to identify the correct overload when I do `A+A` and `B+B`. *I could solve this by doing two lines, potentially using some temporary variable, but this I don't want to do.* How can I get this overload to work for this 'one-liner'?

I presume it is a particularity of Eigen, but am so far unable to understand exactly which particularity and how I can avoid it.

Comment: `A+A` does not return a `ColD` but an Eigen operator object (which is evaluated lazily). Either cast `A+A` to `ColD` or let `multiply` accept such operator objects by making it a template. The same goes for B.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for the reply. That is clearly the solution. Can you help me along with the syntax (and pros and cons) of both approaches?

Comment: Do you actually intend to have different implementations for columns and full matrices? I assume the `2. * A;` is just an example.

Comment: @chtz Exactly. In hindsight I did not state this very well but indeed I have different implementations for columns and matrices. So in that case do you think that using `ColD(A + A)` is the only solution?

Comment: The easiest solution taking a `Derived` (or `MatrixBase<Derived>`) as argument would be to put an `if(Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime)` or just `if(Derived::RowsAtCompileTime==1)` inside the function -- every compiler should be smart enough to optimize away the branch. In C++17 you could also use `if constexpr(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, Eigen's operators do not produce plain matrices or vectors but operation objects (e.g. `Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<...>`).

You can either convert the operation to a plain matrix like so...

```
std::cout << multiply(ColD(A + A)) << std::endl;
std::cout << multiply(MatD(B + B)) << std::endl;
```

... or make `multiply` a template that accepts all kinds of formats. The syntax becomes a bit ugly, however:

```
template <typename Derived>
Eigen::Matrix<
    typename Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar,
    Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::RowsAtCompileTime, 
    Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::ColsAtCompileTime>
    multiply(const Derived& A) 
{
    return 2.0 * A;
}
```

The template parameter is `Derived`, which can be a matrix, a vector, or any of Eigen's operation objects. The return value is a `Eigen::Matrix` whose characteristics we extract from `Derived` via the `traits` template.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!! The template is a bit missy indeed, so I'll stick to the first solution.

Comment: @TomdeGeus I believe the template can be simplified. Consider `template<typename Derived>
auto multiply(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &A){return 2.0*A;}`

Comment: @DavidAce Thanks, that is much simpler indeed. It appears that the two solutions allow two different kinds of usage: a generic function which may be called with many types of matrices, and a more narrow one which can be used to do slightly different operations on different matrix types.

Comment: The `auto` return type will only work with C++14 but it will return an expression template as well (something like CwiseUnaryOp<...>) -- this may or may not be beneficial.  If you want to return the evaluated expression, either write `return (2.0*A).eval();` (together with `auto` as return type). Or change the return type to `typename Derived::PlainMatrix` (this is a shorthand for what you wrote manually in your answer).